# Dynamic, Generic C# REST-like storage solutions

Tags: c#, xml, rest, serialization, json.net

I'm currently a researcher for AI company.
I require a serialization solution that is to store very similar structure wise , but vastly different types, interface/base class, and internal generic lists and arrays. 
I'm working on CS(C#) due to unique requirements of my work, porting to Java for example isn't an option. 
Suffice to say XML doesn't quite cut it - some Nuget packaged upgraded versions of the Microsoft default appear to be a a bit too static or their patterns seem 'clumsy'.

My next line of research Led to JSON (.net).

However I'm unsure if this is the best option - especially considering the complexity of the classes to saved - and the potential for a REST architecture distribution implementation soon.

Thanks for you time, and suggestions. Links to examples of your recommendations containing similarly complex class structures would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out serialization and deserialization of dynamic objects. Your JSON could be as complex as possible. This should give you some idea.

https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/

Comment: Thanks I have indeed experimented with dynamic input type conversion. Unfortunately not enough of the class data was sent through - i'm parsing between projects within one solution (Simulating network transfer above anything). I'll update in time, many thanks!